# How do I copy content from Word Document another with images and links?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I've had some problem when copying content from a Word document to another Word document.
The document where the information should end up in have a header.

So far I have managed to copy the content to the second document and not affecting the header.
However I can't figure out how to bind the relationships for links and Images.

This is my code so far:

```
public static void AddContentToTemplateCopy(
                        string sourceDocumentPath, string endDocumentPath)
{
     using (WordprocessingDocument sourceDoc = 
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(sourceDocumentPath, false))
     using (WordprocessingDocument endDoc = 
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(endDocumentPath, true))
     {
            var sourceMainPart = sourceDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            var sourceBody = sourceMainPart.Document.Body;

            var endSection = endDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>();
            var endDocMainPart = endDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            var sourceBodyClone = sourceBody.CloneNode(true);
            sourceBodyClone.ReplaceChild(endSection.FirstOrDefault().CloneNode(true), sourceBodyClone.Elements<SectionProperties>().FirstOrDefault());
            endDocMainPart.Document.ReplaceChild(sourceBodyClone, endDocMainPart.Document.Body);

            foreach (HyperlinkRelationship link in sourceMainPart.HyperlinkRelationships)
            {
                endDocMainPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(link.Uri, link.IsExternal, link.Id);
            }
}
```

I get the following Error : 'rId6' ID conflicts with the ID of an existing relationship for the specified source.

And the if i have a Image in the content it can't be displayed.

If I zip the document and look at the files in the package I can find the Image but for the same reason as the links the Relation

**So my question is:** How do I bind the links and Images with their "_rels" references? or how do I copy them so that it works..

This is a Relationship link when I have added the link by hand.

```
<Relationship Target="media/image1.jpg" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Id="rId11"/>
```

A picture to show that the link text is copied but have no formatting and that the image can't be displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it easier to try Eric White's [document builder](http://ericwhite.com/blog/documentbuilder-expanded/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you have any experience of working with document builder? Can you perhaps tell me more specifically how it works for images and links. Maybe a link? thx.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the answer by JasonPlutext i managed to use [OpenXML PowerTools (Version 2.2).](http://powertools.codeplex.com/) Keep in mind that the .Net version is 3.5 when importing the project. You Might need to change it. (Supports Open XML 2.5 as well from what I've noticed)

Very simple to create new documents and take parts from old documents.

The code here is in my case where I want the formatting and content from one and then the Header from a template document. The order matters.

Hopefully this will save time for others with the same problem.

```
public static void AddContentToTemplateCopy(string templateDocumentPath, 
                                            string contentDocumentPath, 
                                            List<Source> sources, 
                                            string outName)
    {
        sources = new List<Source>()
        {
            new Source(new WmlDocument(contentDocumentPath),false),
            new Source(new WmlDocument(templateDocumentPath),true),
        };
        DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources, outName);
    }
```